# What is the Maximum volume size of VFAT

Tags: filesystems

- I need to Know the What is the Maximum volume size of VFAT (Maximu file system size to support VFAT).
- I know the Maximum file size of VFAT is 2GB, **I Need the Maximum Volume size of VFAT.**

Rgards,
Vamsi.

Answer (score 5):

[2TB for 512 byte sector size and 16TB for a 4K sector size.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32)